# Columns selection on specific text

Tags: python, pandas

I want to extract specific columns that contain specific names. Below you can see my data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


data = {
         'Names': ['Store (007) Total amount of Sales ',
                   'Store perc (65) Total amount of sales ',
                   'Mall store, aid (005) Total amount of sales',
                   'Increase in the value of sales / Additional seling (22) Total amount of sales',
                   'Dividends (0233) Amount of income tax',
                   'Other income (098) Total amount of Sales',
                   'Other income (0245) Amount of Income Tax',
                    ],
         'Sales':[10,10,9,7,5,5,5],
         
         
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Names',
                                   'Sales',
                             
                                   ])
df
```

This data have some specific columns that I need to be selected in the separate data frame. Keywords for this selection are words `Total amount of Sales` or `Total amount of sales` . These words are placed after the second brackets `)`. Also please take into account that text is no trimmed so empty spaces are possible.

[image]

So can anybody help me how to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) without test cases with `case=False` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['Names'].str.contains('Total amount of Sales', case=False)]
print (df1)
                                               Names  Sales
0                 Store (007) Total amount of Sales      10
1             Store perc (65) Total amount of sales      10
2        Mall store, aid (005) Total amount of sales      9
3  Increase in the value of sales / Additional se...      7
5           Other income (098) Total amount of Sales      5
```

Or if need test `sales` or `Sales` use:

```
df2 = df[df['Names'].str.contains('Total amount of [Ss]ales')]
```